# Untar multiple *.tar.gz.aa *.tar.gz.ab pattern files

Tags: linux

I tarred a folder and split it into tar.gz files of 200mb when zipping. How can I go about unzipping them? Is there a way I can do this in one command or do I have to do each one separately?

Answer (score 17):

You even *cannot* do it separately.

Just undo what you did in reversed order:

- first concatenate them
- then unzip them
- then untar

So you do

```
cat *.tar.gz.* | zcat | tar xvf -
```

or, even shorter,

```
cat *.tar.gz.* | tar xvfz -
```

Comment: The file format is *.tar.gz.aa and *.tar.gz.ab and when I did zcat *.tar.gz.* | tar xvf - it says this : gzip: cm13.backup.tar.gz.aa: not in gzip format
gzip: cm13.backup.tar.gz.ab: not in gzip format

Comment: @HelloMan You are right, I was on the wrong track there: `zcat` treats the file passed to it separately. `cat` must be used there.

Comment: on Ubuntu 22.04, with file format .tar.gz.aa, both 'cat *.tar.gz.** | zcat | tar xvf -' and 'cat *.tar.gz.*| tar xvfz -'  fail with "gzip: stdin: not in gzip format"

Answer (score 2):

You can use the bellow :

```
$ cat *.tar | tar -xvf - -i
```

`cat` command, listed `.tar` files, then listed files will extracted with `tar -xvf - -i` command.